# Apps Script onEdit to add/clear timestamp across multiple sheets if a checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

I've got the script below working except for the bottom portion starting at //3. The initial portion works on my first sheet listed and adds a timestamp if a checkbox is checked, clears it if it is unchecked. However, it only works on the first sheet, and I need it to work on the second sheet listed as well. The data is set up differently on each sheet so that's why I have these broken out. I'd appreciate any guidance, I'm very new to Apps Script and learning so I'm sure it's a novice and silly mistake:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  //1.Change 'Sheet1' to match your sheet name  
  if (r.getColumn() == 1 && ss.getName()=='Sheet1') { // 2. If Edit is done in column 1 make change in column 4(D) then:
    var celladdress ='D'+ r.getRowIndex();
    if(r.getValue() !="" && r.getValue() !=" "){
      ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
    } else{
      ss.getRange(celladdress).clearContent();
}
//3.Change 'Sheet2' to to match your sheet name  
  if (r.getColumn() == 1 && ss.getName()=='Sheet2') { // 4. If Edit is done in column (G) then:
    var celladdress ='G'+ r.getRowIndex();
    if(r.getValue() !="" && r.getValue() !=" "){
      ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
    } else{
      ss.getRange(celladdress).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I thought that an object for searching the sheet name might be able to be used.

  - In this modification `var obj = {Sheet1: "D", Sheet2: "G"}` is used.
  - For example, `obj["Sheet1"]` returns `D`. This is used for the modified script.
- About the checkbox, you can also use `isChecked()` for checking whether the checkbox is checked.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var ss = r.getSheet();
  
  // Prepare an object for searching sheet name.
  var obj = {Sheet1: "D", Sheet2: "G"};

  // Using the object, check the sheet and put or clear the range.
  if (r.getColumn() == 1 && obj[ss.getSheetName()]) {
    var celladdress = obj[ss.getName()] + r.getRowIndex();
    if (r.isChecked()) {
      ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
    } else {
      ss.getRange(celladdress).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

- In this case, the event object is used. But if you want to directly run the function at the script editor, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var r = e.range;
      var ss = r.getSheet();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var r = ss.getActiveCell();
    ```

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new so I don't think the upvote works for me yet but this definitely worked.

Comment: @Chaz Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.